# Angular Date Time Picker ngModel not working

Tags: angular, datetime, angular-ngmodel

l am try to pushing date to firebase database , using [Angular Date Time Picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime) . The problem is , after selected date from input and pushing to database i have empty objects field in database  . Is look like `ngModel`not working . Also i dont have any error in console .

html code

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="Mytime" [owlDateTime]="dt1" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1" placeholder="Date Time">
          <owl-date-time #dt1></owl-date-time>
```

[image]

Any idea please ?

Comment: The docs look pretty comprehensive. Have you tried following any of these examples? https://daniel-projects.firebaseapp.com/owlng/date-time-picker

Comment: i followed everything in docs , also i tried to make normal input and i enter some value on input and i pushed into firebase he is working fine .

Comment: None of the examples use `[(ngModel)]` like your question, though

Comment: @KurtHamilton i want to use `[(ngModel)]` , because how i can push date to firebase without `[(ngModel)]` ?

Comment: @AliGhassancna you put your .ts also?

Comment: @Doflamingo19 Yes

Comment: Also nothing show in console log for `ngModel` Mytime